# change the data of char array

Tags: c, string, arrays, char

i have an array of type char

```
char *arg[100]
```

this array its reading the data from somewhere, when that when i print `arg[0]`, it prints the value "help", and when i print the `arg[1]`, it prints the value "exit".. as an example

what i want exactly is to change the `arg[0]` from "help" to anything else, like "man"

how i can do that???

thank you

the code:

```
int executeCommands(char arg31[])
{       
    pid_t pid;
    int status,number; 
    char *arg3[10]; 
    //char str2[21]; 
    x = 0;
    arg3[x] = strtok(arg31, " \n\t");//this line to tokenize every commands and its arguments from the                          passed array of chars (which is the command)
    while(arg3[x])
    arg3[++x] = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");

    if(NULL!=arg3[0])
    {

        if(strcasecmp(arg3[0],"cat")==0) //done
        {
            int f=0,n;
            char l[1];
            struct stat s;
            if(x!=2)
            {
                    printf("Mismatch argument\n");
                return 0;

            }
else if(strcmp(arg3[0],"help")==0) // done 
        {

            if (strcmp(arg3[1],"cat")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"rm")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"rmdir")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"ls")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"cp")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"mv")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"hi")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"exit1")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"sleep")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"history")==0)
                printf("1");
            else if(strcmp(arg3[1],"type")==0)
                printf("1");
            else
            {   char manarg[] = "man\t";
                arg3[0] = strtok(manarg, " \n\t");
                executeCommands(arg3);
            }
            writeHistory(arg3);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `char *arg[100]` ?

Comment: That is a single string - an array of single characters.  Did you mean char arg[10][100]?

Comment: Sorry about that, its *arg[100]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should put something else in :-

```
strcpy(arg3[0], "blah");
```

boiling your function right down, this compiled just fine for me :-

```
int executeCommands(char arg31[])
{           
    char *arg3[10]; 

    arg3[0] = arg31;

    strcpy(arg3[0], "blah");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

this is the error i get :S

Comment: arg3 is a char**   arg3[0]  is a char*  and arg3[0][0] is a char

Comment: the error is at line 120, which is the line of declaring the executeCommands function..

Comment: oh, what are you passing to excecuatecommands?  are you passing argv to it?    because that would get your error too

Comment: that is the error, that am passing the wrong arg, so i should create another char Char arg[] not a char *arg[]... right??

Comment: hmmmm, I think you need to understand pointers and pointers to pointers....I think it would help you work through this problem.  http://computer.howstuffworks.com/c32.htm

Comment: actually that helped the problem, but now i am facing another problem, i will try to solve, thanks everyone :D

Answer (score 0):

Propably you have `char *arg[100];`

You can do this with:

```
strncpy(arg[0], "man", sizeof(256));
```

Where 256 is number of bytes allocated on memory behind this pointer.
I think you have other value of allocated bytes.

You can do this with this code too:

```
arg[0] = (char*)"man";
```

But in second example you do not good conversion from `const char*` to `char*`

Comment: i tried it it, its not working.. the error is strncpy(arg[0], "man", sizeof(256));

Comment: the error is expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

Comment: hmm, your declaration is char *arg[100]; ?

Comment: the second solution gave me this error


./Rshell.c:377: error: ‘reinterpret_cast’ undeclared (first use in this function)
./Rshell.c:377: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
./Rshell.c:377: error: for each function it appears in.)
./Rshell.c:377: error: expected expression before ‘char’

Comment: can i use strtok(arg31, " \n\t")?? where arg31 is another char array?

Comment: what exactly is the declaration of arg[0]?

Comment: @lele: The second example is C++ only.

Comment: err whats the  declaration of arg?

Answer (score 0):

So the array points to tokens in another string.  You should not copy a new value into that buffer because the new value may be longer than the old value and you don't want to overwrite the next token.

If the new value will be a literal, like "man" you can just do this:

```
arg3[0] = "man";
```

If the new value will be variable string, then something like this:

```
char newToken[64];
newToken[sizeof(newToken)-1] = 0;
strncpy(newToken, "whatever", sizeof(newToken)-1);
arg3[0] = newToken;
```

Comment: actually both ways it gives me the same error

note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char **’

Comment: Are you assigning to arg31 or arg3?  You cannot do that to arg31, it is a char array.  arg3 is an array of pointers and it will work with that.

Comment: it sounds like you are passing the wrong thing in.  like you are doing...   strcpy(arg3, "blah");        that would get the error you are talking about.....

Comment: If you are using arg3, you MUST have an index to dereference.  It must be arg3[0], not arg3 alone.